# Got a error when using handlerService.executeCommand

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm developing a eclipse-plugin and want to use a handler defined by other plugin.Here is the code:

```
IWorkbench w  = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IHandlerService handlerService = w.getService(IHandlerService.class);           
handlerService.executeCommand(TERMINAL_COMMAND, null);
```

But error occur in handlerService.executeCommand `org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException`.

The full stack is:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerService.executeCommand(LegacyHandlerService.java:369)
    at h3c.omni.eclipse.plugin.rest.ApiOpenTerminal.execute(ApiOpenTerminal.java:73)
    at h3c.common.network.protocol.http.server.RestApiServer$RestHandler.handle(RestApiServer.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at h3c.common.network.protocol.http.server.RestApiServer$DefaultHandler.handle(RestApiServer.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.terminal.ui.internal.handler.LaunchTerminalCommandHandler.execute(LaunchTerminalCommandHandler.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    ... 35 more
```

`TERMINAL_COMMAND` is a handler ID`com.terminal.view.ui.command.launchToolbar` like this

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
      <handler
            class="com.terminal.ui.internal.handler.LaunchTerminalCommandHandler"
            commandId="com.terminal.view.ui.command.launchToolbar">
      </handler>
...
</extension
```

I'm sure this handler can be user because other plugins were using it.I think I
use this handler in a wrong way,I just add the plugin which define the `TERMINAL_COMMAND` handler to the `Required Plug-ins`,and add it to the `MANIFEST.MF`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I change the code to  `handlerService.executeCommand("", null);`  and got `org.eclipse.core.commands.common.NotDefinedException`  ,so I can sure that I using the command in a wrong way, So how to use handler in other plugin?

Comment: What is `TERMINAL_COMMAND`? Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. [Edit] your question to show us the extra detail.

Comment: I add the full stack of the problem and the definition of the `TERMINAL_COMMAND `

Comment: The stack trace shows the command is being executed but is getting an NPE in the LaunchTerminalCommandHandler command handler. Maybe this command needs parameters, look at the defining `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point to see how the command is declared.

Comment: The command might also require that the second parameter of executeCommand is a non-null Event.